# If statement inside an inline styling function in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering how can execute an if statement in order to style my rendered text (give it a color) depending on it's value.

`row.var` is a value that I get from a map:

```
<StyledTableCell style = {{
  if ({row.var} > 0) {
    color : 'green';
  else {
    color : "red"
  }   
}} align="right">{row.var}</StyledTableCell>
```

And this does not seems to be the correct syntax or logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style is an object, you cannot put an `if` statement directly inside an object like that. You may however use a ternary to decide what object should be used:

```js
<StyledTableCell 
  style={row.var > 0 ? { color: 'green'} : { color: 'red' }}
  align="right"
>
  {row.var}
</StyledTableCell>
```

Another option is to use the ternary on the value itself:

```js
<StyledTableCell 
  style={{ color: row.var > 0 ? 'green' : 'red'}}
  align="right"
>
  {row.var}
</StyledTableCell>
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute an if statement inside jsx you can use a ternary operator:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

More info about the ternary operator:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator